# Registration page not processing data to database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am developing a website with User registration and login ,after completing the page configuration ,i tried to register it worked perfectly and later next day i tried to register but the page is not loading ,after filling in the data and if i click submit ,it reloads the same register page with no effect ,how to solve this problem

```
  SQL Query Processing code: (class.newuser.php)

 enter code here




       class User 
      {
      public $user_active = 0;
      private $clean_email;
      public $status = false;
      private $clean_password;
      private $clean_username;
      private $unclean_username;
      public $sql_failure = false;
      public $mail_failure = false;
      public $email_taken = false;
      public $username_taken = false;
      public $activation_token = 0;

      function __construct($user,$pass,$email)
      {
      //Used for display only
      $this->unclean_username = $user;

     //Sanitize
     $this->clean_email = sanitize($email);
     $this->clean_password = trim($pass);
     $this->clean_username = sanitize($user);

     if(usernameExists($this->clean_username))
     {
     $this->username_taken = true;
     }
     else if(emailExists($this->clean_email))
     {
     $this->email_taken = true;
     }
    else
    {
     //No problems have been found.
    $this->status = true;
    }
    }

    public function userPieAddUser()
    {
    global $db,$emailActivation,$websiteUrl,$db_table_prefix;

  //Prevent this function being called if there were construction errors
  if($this->status)
   {
    //Construct a secure hash for the plain text password
    $secure_pass = generateHash($this->clean_password);

    //Construct a unique activation token
    $this->activation_token = generateactivationtoken();

    //Do we need to send out an activation email?
    if($emailActivation)
    {
        //User must activate their account first
        $this->user_active = 0;

        $mail = new userPieMail();

        //Build the activation message
        $activation_message = lang("ACTIVATION_MESSAGE",array("{$websiteUrl}/",$this->activation_token));

        //Define more if you want to build larger structures
        $hooks = array(
            "searchStrs" => array("#ACTIVATION-MESSAGE","#ACTIVATION-KEY","#USERNAME#"),
            "subjectStrs" => array($activation_message,$this->activation_token,$this->unclean_username)
        );

        /* Build the template - Optional, you can just use the sendMail function 
        Instead to pass a message. */
        if(!$mail->newTemplateMsg("new-registration.txt",$hooks))
        {
            $this->mail_failure = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //Send the mail. Specify users email here and subject. 
            //SendMail can have a third parementer for message if you do not wish to build a template.

            if(!$mail->sendMail($this->clean_email,"New User"))
            {
                $this->mail_failure = true;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Instant account activation
        $this->user_active = 1;
    }   


    if(!$this->mail_failure)
    {
            //Insert the user into the database providing no errors have been found.
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `".$db_table_prefix."users` (
                    `username`,
                    `username_clean`,
                    `password`,
                    `email`,
                    `activationtoken`,
                    `last_activation_request`,
                    `LostpasswordRequest`, 
                    `active`,
                    `group_id`,
                    `sign_up_date`,
                    `last_sign_in`
                    )
                    VALUES (
                    '".$db->sql_escape($this->unclean_username)."',
                    '".$db->sql_escape($this->clean_username)."',
                    '".$secure_pass."',
                    '".$db->sql_escape($this->clean_email)."',
                    '".$this->activation_token."',
                    '".time()."',
                    '0',
                    '".$this->user_active."',
                    '1',
                    '".time()."',
                    '0'
                    )";

        return $db->sql_query($sql);
    }
}
} 
}
?>
```

HTML register.php

```
enter code here





    <?php
require_once("models/config.php");


//Prevent the user visiting the logged in page if he/she is already logged in
if(isUserLoggedIn()) { header("Location: index.php"); die(); }
     ?>


    <?php


    //Forms posted
     if(!empty($_POST))
     {
    $errors = array();
    $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    $confirm_pass = trim($_POST["passwordc"]);

    //Perform some validation
    //Feel free to edit / change as required

    if(minMaxRange(5,25,$username))
    {
        $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_USER_CHAR_LIMIT",array(5,25));
    }
    if(minMaxRange(8,50,$password) && minMaxRange(8,50,$confirm_pass))
    {
        $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_PASS_CHAR_LIMIT",array(8,50));
    }
    else if($password != $confirm_pass)
    {
        $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_PASS_MISMATCH");
    }
    if(!isValidemail($email))
    {
        $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_INVALID_EMAIL");
    }
    //End data validation
    if(count($errors) == 0)
    {   
            //Construct a user object
            $user = new User($username,$password,$email);

            //Checking this flag tells us whether there were any errors such as possible data duplication occured
            if(!$user->status)
            {
                if($user->username_taken) $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_USERNAME_IN_USE",array($username));
                if($user->email_taken)    $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_EMAIL_IN_USE",array($email));       
            }
            else
            {
                if(!$user->userPieAddUser())
                {
                    if($user->mail_failure) $errors[] = lang("MAIL_ERROR");
                    if($user->sql_failure)  $errors[] = lang("SQL_ERROR");
                }
            }
    }
   if(count($errors) == 0) 
   {
            if($emailActivation)
            {
                 $message = lang("ACCOUNT_REGISTRATION_COMPLETE_TYPE2");
            } else {
                 $message = lang("ACCOUNT_REGISTRATION_COMPLETE_TYPE1");
            }
   }
   }
       ?>
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>Registration | <?php echo $websiteName; ?> </title>
      <?php require_once("head_inc.php"); ?>
      </head>
       <body>
       <div class="modal-ish">
        <div class="modal-header">
       <h2>Sign Up</h2>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">

       <div id="success">

       <p><?php echo $message ?></p>

       </div>

        <div id="regbox">
            <form name="newUser" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">

            <p>
                <label>Username:</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" />
            </p>

            <p>
                <label>Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" />
            </p>

            <p>
                <label>Re-type Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="passwordc" />
            </p>

            <p>
                <label>Email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" />
            </p>

  </div>           
  </div>



         <div class="modal-footer">
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="new" id="newfeedform" value="Register" />
             </div>  

            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>
        <p style="margin-top:30px; text-align:center;"><a href="login.php">Login</a> / <a href="forgot-password.php">Forgot Password?</a> / <a href="<?php echo $websiteUrl; ?>">Home Page</a></p>

       </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: Have you done ANY basic debugging yourself? Put some echoes into the processing logic to see if/where it craps out? Checked the generated $sql for errors?

Answer (score 0):

Its all due to div tags:

2 divisions closed within the form tag but they are opened outside the form tag.

So try by enclosing the whole form within one div(regbox) Including submit.

And make sure that no div is closed within form tag which is opened outside form tag.